# cakephp Database Design

Tags: database, cakephp, associations

My data structure is as follows:

```
Company hasMany Regions
Region hasMany Markets
Market hasMany Stores
Store hasMany Employees
```

I also have the appropriate belongsTo where necessary.

I used foreign keys for associations. For example, each store has market_id.

When I delete a Company record, the correct Region is also deleted. However, it occurred to me that I also need all associated Markets, Stores, and Employees to be deleted. Or if I deleted a Market, I would need all Stores and Employees deleted.

What is the most appropriate manner of accomplishing this?

1. Would I add additional foreign keys to the tables? For example, would Stores need region_id and company_id in addition to market_id?

Answer (score 1):

Use dependent association:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasmany

> **dependent**: When dependent is set to true, recursive model deletion is
>   possible. In this example, Comment records will be deleted when their
>   associated User record has been deleted.

You don't need to add the additional foreign keys.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the reply. This works for one level. I added dependent to the Company hasMany Regions model. This produced the expected result, associated regions were deleted. However, markets, stores, and employees were not deleted. (I did add dependent to all models).  Next, I tried adding Company hasMany Markets to the Company model. This results in the following error: "Fatal error: Class declarations may not be nested..." I need the recursive deletion to spread over many tables, from Company to Region to Market to Store to Employee based on deleting Company.

Comment: Ok I got it! The delete call in CompaniesController.php needs to have cascade set to true. This looks like $this->Company->delete($id, true). Additionally for starting at other levels, if I start the delete at Market I would add cascade to true to also have associated Stores and Employees deleted.